# send a file from a server to another server use rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a server that generates a file, I want to send that file to another server, when the file is ready.
 so the server that receives file should always listen 
and I have used Django rest framework, does anybody have a link to help me?

Comment: 1. Is there a request that causes the file to generate? 2. Do you want to send the file from server 1 to server 2 via a REST call, or through some other means?

Comment: yes end of one function creates the file, no I mean this two server write by Django rest framework

Comment: Just so I comprehend, Server A has a function that creates a file, and you want Server A to send a file to Server B via a request using Django Rest Framework?

Comment: I should write model serializer and view to both servers

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't think I fully understand the question.

Comment: yes  exactly I want to send the request to server B at the end of a function

Comment: Ok, I will come up with an example of what I think you are asking for then and hopefully this will at least lead you in the right direction.

Comment: grammar correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Server A (Server receiving file from Server B)**

models.py

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    # Other fields you are interested in saving
    file_data = models.FileField()
```

serializers.py

```
class TestModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

view.py

```
class TestModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TestModel.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
    serializer_class = TestModelSerializer
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'test', views.TestModelViewSet)
urlpatters = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls))
]
```

**Server B (192.168.5.5) (Send file to Server A)**

file_generator.py

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('http://192.168.5.5/api/test', files={'file.txt': f})
```

Comment: tnx for helping I write server A with ur help. now when I try to post to server A face this error   POST /api/update_log HTTP/1.0" 400 40